# Tomcat 7 + Grails 3.1.10 - ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpUpgradeHandler

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, grails, tomcat7

**Development environment:**

- Grails 3.1.10
- Java: version "1.8.0_72" (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit)
- Ubuntu 14.04

**Production environment (app deployment):**

- Java: version "1.8.0_101-b13" (Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
- Tomcat: 7.0.57

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    //compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"

    compile 'org.grails.plugins:views-json:1.0.0'

    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2"
    compile 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1'
    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:grails-console:2.0.8'

    //deve ser inserido para rodar num tomcat externo
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
```

Since I'm not using the Grails embedded Tomcat it's necessary to change the dependecy `"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"` from **compile** to **provided**.

**I'm facing the following issue:**

The app runs perfectly fine on my Development environment, but when I deploy the app to Server environment I get the following exception:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/api/samplingPlan] due to exception [javax/servlet/http/HttpUpgradeHandler]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpUpgradeHandler
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1336)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:3290)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3288)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3265)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:285)
    at grails.views.mvc.GenericGroovyTemplateView$HttpViewRequest.$getStaticMetaClass(GenericGroovyTemplateView.groovy)
    at grails.views.mvc.GenericGroovyTemplateView$HttpViewRequest.<init>(GenericGroovyTemplateView.groovy)
    at grails.views.mvc.GenericGroovyTemplateView.prepareWritable(GenericGroovyTemplateView.groovy:96)
    at grails.views.mvc.GenericGroovyTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(GenericGroovyTemplateView.groovy:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
    at Tomcat 7.0.57org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at br.com.sgsgeosol.sampling.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:281)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:143)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpUpgradeHandler
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 125 common frames omitted
```

**Some important facts:**

- The app runs perfectly fine on my Development Environment;
- This exception occurs in a REST call. Others call works fine (GSP, for example).
- We have others app (Grails 2.5.x) running perfectly fine on OpenJDK/Tomcat 7.0.57;
- We have others app (non Grails) running perfectly fine on OpenJDK/Tomcat 7.0.57;

**Question:**

Why I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` on `javax.servlet.http.HttpUpgradeHandler` when I depoly my app to Tomcat 7.0.57?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is upgrade to Tomcat 8.

The image below shows that Tomcat 7.0.57 uses the Servlet Specification 3.0. The problem is happening because the `servlet-api.jar` found in the folder `Tomcat-7.0.57/lib` doesn't have the class `javax.servlet.http.HttpUpgradeHandler`. On the other hand, the `servlet-api.jar` used by Tomcat 8 has the respective class.

[image]